# NiFi Build Errors

Tags: maven, cloudera-cdh, apache-nifi

I'm trying to build Apache NiFi after cloning it from https://github.com/apache/nifi and it keeps failing on the tests on the nifi-standard-processors project.  I opened up the output file in the surefire-reports directory and there's the below error that it can't run program "cmd" in directory /var/test, because no such file or directory exists.  The first time I ran the install it didn't exist, but I created it and I still get the error message.  I do a sanity check every time to make sure the directory still does exist.  Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue?  I'm only taking a very few steps to do this.  They are posted below.  I'm logged on as root on a CentOS Linux VM.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Steps:

1. cd /tmp
2. git clone https://github.com/apache/nifi
3. cd nifi
4. mvn clean install

[main] ERROR org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteProcess - ExecuteProcess[id=a8d6b3a3-befa-4b74-a962-330bd021ec7b] Failed to create process due to java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/var/test"): error=2, No such file or directory: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/var/test"): error=2, No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is due to a recent commit "solving" this ticket[1]. I actually already reopened[2] it due to failures on TravisCI and the contributor is currently working on a fix.

In order to build now, you can tell maven to "skip tests" by running the command with the proper flag: `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2905

[2] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2905?focusedCommentId=15603258&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15603258

Comment: Thank you!  That was driving me crazy.  The weird thing was when I used "mvn clean install" I got the error message from my question, but when I used "mvn -T C2.0 clean install", I got a different error on the nifi-toolkit-encrypt-config project.

Comment: Not a problem, thank you for posting the question! The "-T C2.0" flag runs the maven build in multithreaded fashion. When it does this it will check your local m2 repo for the dependencies it needs and if it's there then it will use them. Since you're building the SNAPSHOT version, the dependencies exist in your local m2 repo already but may be from an older build (like before a certain parameter was added). So you could be reusing old dependencies before the new ones got built. Leading to odd errors in random parts of the project.